# Как установить один changedlistener для нескольких edittext?

Tags: java, android

У меня для нескольких абсолютно одинаковых edittext установлен абсолютно одинаковый textchangedlistener. Можно ли установить его для сразу всех нужных edittext?

```
Height.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                makeClean();
            }
        });
```

Comment: нужно реализовать полноценный, а не анонимный класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставить один обработчик для нескольких edittext.

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                makeClean();
            }
        };

Height.addTextChangedListener(tw);
Height1.addTextChangedListener(tw);
...
```